# How to find all edges of a node's maximal clique in networkx?

Tags: python-2.7, networkx

I have a large graph made in networkx, and I used the clique function to find the largest clique for each node:

```
thecliques = nx.node_clique_number(mygraph)
```

However, no matter how much I search, I am unable to find the members of the maximal clique for each node. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

May not be computationally optimal as it enumerates all cliques, but you can use:

```
    G= nx.barabasi_albert_graph(20, 2, seed=1234)
    dict_of_cliques=nx.cliques_containing_node(G,nodes=None,cliques=None)
    print dict_of_cliques
```

Output is a dictionary {node:list of lists of nodes in clique, including node}. IE:

```
{0: [[0, 3, 2], [0, 3, 7], [0, 4, 8], [0, 5], [0, 9, 13], [0, 15], [0, 17], [0, 19]], 1: [[1, 2, 11], [1, 4], [1, 5]], 2: [[0, 3, 2], [1, 2, 11], [6, 2], [18, 2]], 3: [[0, 3, 2], [0, 3, 7], [12, 3]], 4: [[0, 4, 8], [1, 4], [6, 4], [12, 4], [18, 4]], 5: [[0, 5], [1, 5], [14, 5]], 6: [[6, 2], [6, 10, 16], [6, 10, 9], [6, 4]], 7: [[0, 3, 7]], 8: [[0, 4, 8]], 9: [[0, 9, 13], [6, 10, 9], [14, 9]], 10: [[6, 10, 16], [6, 10, 9], [10, 19]], 11: [[1, 2, 11], [11, 17]], 12: [[12, 3], [12, 4], [12, 15]], 13: [[0, 9, 13]], 14: [[14, 9], [14, 5]], 15: [[0, 15], [12, 15]], 16: [[6, 10, 16]], 17: [[0, 17], [11, 17]], 18: [[18, 2], [18, 4]], 19: [[0, 19], [10, 19]]}
```

Crucially you can see here that the maximal cliques may not be unique, so it is up to you how you will select the largest clique.